# Nifi: Can I use variables for the Kerberos Principal and the Kerberos Keytab?

Tags: variables, expression, kerberos, apache-nifi

I have files coming in from three different sources to a "PutHDFS" processor. These three sources all have separate keytabs and are going to separate directories. Since the name of the source is in the filename, I was able to create a variable called "source_name" and I can use this to make a directory just fine, something like this:

```
/my/hdfs/directory/${source_name}/reports
```

I wanted to do something similar with the the Kerberos Principal and the Kerberos Keytab, like this:

**Kerberos Principal**: ${source_name}@acme.com

**Kerberos Keytab**: /home/nifi/keytabs/${source_name}.keytab

However, Nifi is reading these values literally and I get errors that it "couldn't authenticate ${source_name}@acme.com"

The Nifi documentation says that these fields support expression language, but in Nifi itself (version 1.7), it says that the fields only support "Variable Registry Only." Despite extensive searching, I'm still unable to determine what "Variable Registry Only" means. Am I forced to hard-code the kerberos values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression language allows referencing values from several different sources and it works in a hierarchy which is described here:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Using_Custom_Properties

When it says "Variable Registry Only" it means values from incoming flow files are not accessible to the expression language statements of that property.

The primary reason for this is usually because those values need to be used in a way that can't be done per flow file. For example, the HDFS processors need to perform a kerberos login when the processor starts and then periodically renew the ticket. Doing this for an infinite number of incoming flow file values becomes problematic to manage.

Update:

This may be a better description of the hierarchy of values expression language can access:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/expression/ExpressionLanguageScope.java#L20-L38

Comment: Your reply is very much appreciated - thanks! I'm curious, though...when you say, "values from incoming flow files are not accessible to the expression language statements of that property", could you tell me what kind of values *would* be accessible to the EL statements of that property?

Comment: It is described in that link where it says "From variable registry:"

Comment: Basically variables in a custom variables file specified in nifi.properties, variables specified in the UI by right-clicking on a process group, system properties, and environment variables

Comment: Also see the new link I just added in the answer